# InvokeRepeating и Корутины (coroutines) продолжают работать в деактивированном скрипте. Что делать?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда я запускаю метод `InvokeRepeating` в скрипте, то после его деактивации (компонента/скрипта) продолжается работать метод, запущенный с помощью `InvokeRepeating`. Аналогично с корутинами. Почему? И что делать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К сожалению или к счастью — это особенности работы методов.

В целом, если в скрипте используется `InvokeRepeating` или Корутины (coroutines), то следует помнить что:

**Для InvokeRepeating:**

- если деактивировать объект весь объект (`gameObject.SetActive(false)`), на котором висит данный скрипт — `InvokeRepeating` все равно будет продолжать работать
- если устанавливать `disable` только для компонента — `InvokeRepeating` все равно будет продолжать работать

**Для корутин:**

- если деактивировать объект  (`gameObject.SetActive(false)`), на котором висит данный скрипт —  корутина **останавливается**
- если устанавливать `disable` только для компонента — корутина все равно будет продолжать работать

---

Если хочется отключить работу `InvokeRepeating` когда отключаешь компонент или объект — можно воспользоваться методом **[MonoBehaviour.OnDisable()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDisable.html)** и **[MonoBehaviour.CancelInvoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.CancelInvoke.html)** / **[MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html)**. И, в принципе, в `OnDisable` можно написать логику при выключении скрипта/объекта, при необходимости

```
void OnDisable() {
    CancelInvoke();     
}
```

А включить заново можно в **[OnEnable()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnEnable.html)**

---

Пример:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class InvokeRepeatingNotStop : MonoBehaviour {

    private int i = 0;  
    void Start() {
        InvokeRepeating("CountUp", 0.0f, 0.5f);
        Invoke("Disable", 3.0f);
    }

    void Disable() {
        enabled = false;
//      gameObject.SetActive(false);        
    }

    void CountUp() {
        i = i + 1;
        Debug.Log("i=" + i);
    }

    void OnDisable() {
//      CancelInvoke();     
    }
}
```

Если раскоментировать `CancelInvoke()` , то работа прекратится